# Can user identifying information in Dropbox be derived from subscription data?

Tags: http, cloud-computing

I've noticed that my Dropbox installation really loves sending unencrypted information over the net including a "user_id" and it's user-agent.

What i want to know is if it's possible at all to determine who owns the account from the user_id or from something else in the url.

This is an example of the url with the numbers changed.

```
/subscribe?host_int=1234567890&ns_map=12345678_1234567890123&user_id=12345678&nid=0&ts=1234567890
```